# Looking for an Ember way to handle filtering

Tags: ember.js, observers

Given a product list page with some filters (`query`, `status`, `page`, `perPage`) that cannot work all together:

- When the user writes a `query`, the `status` filter should be cleared, and the `page` set to 1.
- When the user select a `status` filter, the `query` filter should be cleared, and the `page` set to 1.
- When the user changes the `perPage`, the `page` is set to 1 (the other filters stays as they are)
- When the user changes the `page`, filters stays as they are.

Here is how I tried to implement it:

```
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  query: null,
  status: null,
  page: 1,
  perPage: 15,

  queryDidChange: function() {
    this.setProperties({
      status: null,
      page: 1
    });
  }.observes('query'),

  statusDidChange: function() {
    this.setProperties({
      query: null,
      page: 1
    });
  }.observes('status'),

  perPageDidChange: function() {
    this.set('page', 1);
  }.observes('perPage'),

  parametersDidChange: function() {
    this.send('reloadModel');
  }.observes('query', 'status', 'page', 'perPage'),

  actions: {
    reloadModel: function() {
      // code omitted which makes API call using all filters set
    }
  }
});
```

But when the `query` change, the `queryDidChange` observer is called, which clears the `status`. As the `status` changed, the `statusDidChange` observer is called, which clears the `query`, etc.

This kind of solution may not be the best, but I would like to keep an "Ember way" to do that, and use only the public API (eg not `_suspendObservers`).

How could I achieve this ? Perhaps using a run loop somewhere ?

**EDIT**

Please also notice that I know the view could send actions instead of just changing properties, so the controller will looks like this:

```
 App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   actions: {
     queryDidChange: function() {
       this.setProperties({
         status: null,
         page: 1
       });
       this.send('reloadModel');
     },
     // code omitted
   }
 });
```

But this solution seems a bit verbose and do not use the observer & binding power, so I hope there is a way to do this better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to suspend observers in Ember but yuo can achieve this with conditionals in your observer functions

```
queryDidChange: function() {
  if(this.get('query')){
    this.setProperties({
      status: null,
      page: 1
    });
  }
}.observes('query'),

statusDidChange: function() {
  if(this.get('status')){
    this.setProperties({
      query: null,
      page: 1
    });
  }
}.observes('status'),
```

Comment: Thanks, but it cannot work for all cases. For example, when the `query` changes, the `page` is set to `1` by its observer, so the `parametersDidChange` is called two times (because both query and page changes). Even if I remove the `parametersDidChange` observer and just do a `this.send('reloadModel');` at the end of each observer, it will not works: If the user has chosen a `status`, asked the 2nd `page`, when he wants to clear the `status`, the page needs to be set to `1`. With the `if(this.get('status'))` condition, the page will not be cleared as the status will be `null`